# Ruby On Rails Refresh Form Values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, onsubmit

Hi I have a basic form in one of my Ruby On Rails views, it has an input tag and a placeholder. When I submit the form and then try to add another entry the values are kept from previously, what is the simplest way to clear the form fields after submitting. I guess I need to call some javascript onsubmit action when the form is submitted?

If someone could show me a simple example it would be great

Comment: its bit difficult to say something unless you show some of your code of what you are doing

Comment: in java script, you can call "reset()" on the form

Comment: i dont think reset would work, rails might be using the previous cached object and he might be interested in showing the updated values in fields

Comment: Yeah it is just a simple form that adds a bit of text, and I show the values on another page in a list.

Comment: What does your create action look like?